# combine render node on richtext contentful into one div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, contentful, richtext

I want to have more control over how to render rich text, like in this particular case I want to put links and assets into one div, so I can control the style, like making it display flex.

here is the current code :

```
const Follow = ({ children, node }) => 
  <div className="follow-container">
    {console.log(children)}
    {/* {console.log(children.map((i) => i ))} */}
    {/* <img  src={children.data.target.file.url} alt="nft" className="img"/> */}
    {/* {console.log(node)} */}
    <div>
    {/* {children.map((node) =>
        <li key={node.id} >
          {node}
        </li>
      )} */}
      
    </div>
  </div>

const follow = {
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Follow>{children}</Follow>,
    // [BLOCKS.HYPERLINK]: (node ) => <Follow>{node}</Follow>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: (node, children) => <Follow>{node}</Follow>,
  },
}
```

i commented out, because I got an error.

this the result of `console.log(children)`

[image]

Comment: What's the error and/or the console output?

Comment: for which one ? all of it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `INLINES.HYPERLINK` rather than `BLOCKS.HYPERLINK`.

Try this:

```
[INLINES.HYPERLINK]: (node) => <Follow>{node}</Follow>
```

Make sure to import `INLINES` from `"@contentful/rich-text-types"`.